# How to sort a list based on two values

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a list in which I want to sort based on two values date and the status like this:

```
pollsList.sort((a, b) => b.active.compareTo(a.active));

  pollsList.sort((a, b) {
    return b.actualStartDatetime.compareTo(a.actualStartDatetime);
  });
```

where active == 90 if it's active and -90 if it's not.

I want to sort the list based on the date and then based on the date.

I want the newest at the top and always the closed to be after the active items.

But this will result the list only being sorted by the date. How do I sort it by both values?

Comment: Can u share the List Please

Answer (score 42):

You want to sort the list so that a later start time is sorted before an earlier start time, and if both elements have the same start time, then sort active elements before inactive elements.

What you have attempted is to sort the list twice. That only works if the sorting algorithm is *stable*, that is, if elements that are equal wrt. the second sort comparison stay in the order they were put by the first sort. Dart's sort does not promise to be stable, so this is not a safe approach. Even if it appears to work, it is quite possible to have a sorting algorithm that is stable for small lists and not for larger lists.

What you should do instead is to create a single comparison function that does both compares at once. First compare the start times. If those are not equal, you are done, otherwise compare the activities as well.

```
pollsList.sort((a, b) {
  int cmp = b.actualStartDatetime.compareTo(a.actualStartDatetime);
  if (cmp != 0) return cmp;
  return b.active.compareTo(a.active);
});
```

If you want all inactive elements to be sorted before all active elements, and then have each of these groups sorted by start time, you do the comparison in the opposite order:

```
pollsList.sort((a, b) {
  int cmp = b.active.compareTo(a.active);
  if (cmp != 0) return cmp;
  return b.actualStartDatetime.compareTo(a.actualStartDatetime);
});
```

Comment: This is the same.. will display some closed in the middle of the list between open ones...

Comment: That's intended, it sorts *primarily* on start time, and only uses active state as a tie-breaker if the start time is the same. If you want all inactive before all active, the comparisons should be done in the other order. I'll add that as an example as well.

Comment: This solution helped me partially to setup 3-4 level sort. Thanks Irn.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 11):

i solve this by making two columns into one.
"${a.active}${a.actualStartDatetime}" and compare it to b.

```
data.sort((a, b) =>  ("${a.active}${a.actualStartDatetime}").toString()
.compareTo(("${b.status}${b.actualStartDatetime.toUpperCase()}").toString()));
```

Comment: I searched for comparing multiple fields and this is the easiest solution. Thanks

Comment: Very nice!  Simple and effective :)  thank you!

Answer (score 3):

This is not the most elegant, but it's fairly straight forward and worked for me:

1. Divide your original list into 2 new lists based on the first sorting criteria;
2. Sort each new list by the second criteria;
3. Finally, combine the 2 new lists into a final, sorted list;

For example:

```
    List<Polls> activePollsList;
    List<Polls> inactivePollsList;
    List<Polls> finalSortedPollsList;
    
    activePollsList.addAll(pollsList.where((Poll poll) => poll.isActive == true));
    activePollsList.sort((a, b) => a.actualStartDateTime.compareTo(b.actualStartDateTime));
    
    inactivePollsList.addAll(pollsList.where((Polls poll) => poll.isActive == false));
    inactivePollsList.sort((a, b) => a.actualStartDateTime.compareTo(b.actualStartDateTime));
    
    finalSortedPollsList = activePollsList + inActivePollsList;
```

That `finalSortedList` will retain the sorting done by the two lists.

Note in the above I'm making the assumption that your `pollsList` is a list of custom objects called `Polls`, but you would want to change `Poll` in the above code to whatever your custom object is named.

Again, not the most elegant solution, but until Dart allows for multiple sorting criteria this worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

A more generic way to sort lists based on two or more criteria consists of using a [comparator function](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.16.1/dart-core/Comparator.html).

The [sort](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.16.1/dart-core/List/sort.html) method that is available for Dart lists accepts a comparator function as an optional parameter.

In the example below a list with entries of type `MyWidget` (which have the attributes: `title`, `time`, and `status` are sorted in different ways without the need to create and merge separate lists.

```
/// The current status of the widget.
enum Status { open, closed }

// A comparator function for object of type `Status`.
int statusComparator(left, right) {
  if (left == right) return 0;
  if (left == Status.open) return -1;
  return 1;
}

/// DateTime Comparator based on year-month-day  only.
int timeComparator(left, right) {
  var result = -left.year.compareTo(right.year);
  result = result == 0 ? -left.month.compareTo(right.month) : result;
  result = result == 0 ? -left.day.compareTo(right.day) : result;
  return result;
}

/// Sample Widget Class
/// Implements Comparable and requires a `compareTo` method. 
class MyWidget implements Comparable {
  MyWidget(this.title, {this.status = Status.open}) : time = DateTime.now();

  late DateTime time;
  String title;
  Status status;

  @override
  String toString() {
    return '$title ${time.day}-${time.month}-${time.year} ${status.name}';
  }

  /// Default method used for sorting by title > time > status.
  @override
  int compareTo(other) {
    int result = title.compareTo(other.title);
    result = result == 0 ? timeComparator(time, other.time) : result;
    result = result == 0 ? statusComparator(status, other.status) : result;
    return result;
  }

  /// Additional comparator used for sorting by status > time > title.
  static int openFirstComparator<T extends MyWidget>(T left, T right) {
    var result = statusComparator(left.status, right.status);
    result = result == 0 ? timeComparator(left.time, right.time) : result;
    return result == 0 ? left.title.compareTo(right.title) : result;
  }
}

void main() {
  var list = [
    MyWidget('Carol', status: Status.closed)..time = DateTime(2018),
    MyWidget('Carol')..time = DateTime(2018),
    MyWidget('Carol')
      ..time = DateTime(2022)
      ..status = Status.closed,
    MyWidget('Bernard')..time = DateTime(2020),
    MyWidget('Anne'),
    MyWidget('Anne', status: Status.closed),
    MyWidget('Bernard', status: Status.closed),
  ];

  /// Default sorting by title > date > status using the `compareTo` method.
  print('Sorted by title > date > status');
  print(list..sort());

  print('');

  /// Sorted by status, date and title using a custom comparator.
  print('Sorted by status > date > title');
  print(list..sort(MyWidget.openFirstComparator));
}
```

Running the program displays:

```
$ dart main.dart
Sorted by title > date > status
[Anne 2-3-2022 open, Anne 2-3-2022 closed, Bernard 2-3-2022 closed, Bernard 1-1-2020 open, Carol 1-1-2022 closed, Carol 1-1-2018 open, Carol 1-1-2018 closed]

Sorted by status > date > title
[Anne 2-3-2022 open, Bernard 1-1-2020 open, Carol 1-1-2018 open, Anne 2-3-2022 closed, Bernard 2-3-2022 closed, Carol 1-1-2022 closed, Carol 1-1-2018 closed]
```

Tip: To quickly run the code, copy it and paste it into the [dartpad](https://www.dartpad.dev/) editor.

Answer (score 0):

I have a fairly simple solution for multiple fields sort by concatenating them all to a big long string and then they will sort themselves. It works for me so anyone may give it a try.

```
  listOpenOrders.sort(((a, b) {
      return ("${a.deliveryDate?.millisecondsSinceEpoch}${a.customerName}${a.itemCode}")
          .compareTo(
              "${b.deliveryDate?.millisecondsSinceEpoch}${b.customerName}${b.itemCode}");
    }));
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to the slew of answers here, I present to you a generic solution that can sort by an *unlimited* number of properties for any model you may have.

I'll start with what it looks like to use it first:

```dart
pollsList.sort(multiPropertyCompare([
        ((t) => t.actualStartDatetime, ascending: true),
        ((t) => t.active, ascending: false),
        // You can add all the properties you need...
        ((t) => t.somethingElse, ascending: true),
        ((t) => t.yetAnotherProperty, ascending: false),
      ]));
```

Here it is:

```dart
int Function(T, T) multiPropertyCompare<T>(
  List<(Comparable<Object?> Function(T), {bool ascending})> properties,
) {
  return (T a, T b) {
    for (final (propertyExtractor, :ascending) in properties) {
      final (x, y) = ascending ? (a, b) : (b, a);
      final result = propertyExtractor(x).compareTo(propertyExtractor(y));
      if (result != 0) {
        return result;
      }
    }
    return 0;
  };
}
```

If you need to call the function yourself (as opposed to passing it to the `sort` method, for example), it would look something like this. Here's an example of implementing the `compareTo` method of `Comparable`. Note you need to add the type argument!

```dart
@override
int compareTo(Transaction other) {
  return multiPropertyCompare<Transaction>([ // <- Type argument here!
    ((t) => t.date, ascending: true),
    ((t) => t.destinationId, ascending: true),
    ((t) => t.sourceId, ascending: true),
    ((t) => t.amount, ascending: true),
    ((t) => t.fee, ascending: true),
    ((t) => t.type, ascending: true),
  ])(this, other);
}
```